# Tripwire skipping files?

Tags: security, ids, tripwire

**TL;DR:**

Question: how do I configure Tripwire to watch EVERYTHING that is below a certain path? My current config seems to only be looking at certain files / directories in a given path instead of everything.

**Background / Full story:**

I've recently installed Tripwire on a server that had some vulnerable PHP code. I added a rule called "Websites" that includes a number of sites that are run from the server (snippet below).

```
 # Rulset for websites
 (
   rulename = "Websites",
   severity = $(SIG_HI),
   emailto = "webmaster@hackedsite.com"
 )
 {
   /home/foouser1/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser2/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser3/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser4/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser5/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser6/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser7/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser8/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser9/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser10/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser11/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
   /home/foouser12/www/ -> $(SEC_CRIT) (recurse = 1);
 }
```

I then updated the policy using:

`/usr/sbin/twadmin --create-polfile -S site.key /etc/tripwire/twpol.txt`

I entered my site key as expected, and the policy was updated without error.

When I run a check, there are no errors and no violations.

Then, to test it, I added an extra space to one of the files (`/home/foouser1/www/foo/bar/js/script.js`), which had previously (and repeatedly) been compromised. This should trigger a violation.

Re-running the check (`tripwire --check -R Websites` -v) shows several issues:

1. Tripwire was ignoring the file, even thought it is below the declared file path `/home/foouser1/www`.
2. It scans a bunch of files that are in `/home/foouser1/www`, but not all of them.

Finally, when I compare the directory contents of `/home/foouser1/www` to the number of files scanned by tripwire, there is a huge difference.

`find /home/foouser1/www/ -type f -print | wc -l` shows me there are 3,000+ files in that directory that should be watched by tripwire.

`find /home/foouser1/www/ -type d -print | wc -l` shows me there are 192 sub directories in that directory that should be watched by tripwire.

Tripwire reports that it only looked at 192 objects.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that (recurse=1) is not needed. Recursive checking of files and subdirectories is on by default. But, in order to capture miniscule changes (single-byte changes, for example) you need to check the hash of the file (SHA is preferred). So, you can use the following variable as mask:

```
SEC_HACK_DETECT = $(IgnoreNone)-a ; # Files that should not change
```

Between these two changes, Tripwire then works as expected.

Comment: Is this still valid with the new version of tripwire? seems like the variable is updated to be used as SHa -> `SEC_CRIT      = $(IgnoreNone)-SHa ;`. Also can you explain what does the '-a' means ? Why not using -SHa ?